# Convert reflect.value to reflect.method

Tags: reflection, go

I have the fallowing:

```
func NewMethodDescriptor(typ interface{}) *MethodDescriptor {

    reflectedMethod := reflect.ValueOf(typ)
    methodType := reflectedMethod.Type
    paramCount := methodType.NumIn() - 1
    ...
```

But when I try:

```
NewMethodDescriptor(func(){})
```

I get this compile time error:

```
methodType.NumIn undefined (type func() reflect.Type has no field or method NumIn)
```

Comment: `reflectedMethod.Type` returns a function. You have to call that function to get the type, so `methodType := reflectedMethod.Type()`.

Comment: @alvivi:Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific:

- `reflectedMethod.Type` returns the function [`func (v Value) Type() Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Type)
- `reflectedMethod.Type()` returns the result, meaning  v's type.

You can see a more complete example in "[Fun with the reflection package to analyse any function.](https://coderwall.com/p/b5dpwq/fun-with-the-reflection-package-to-analyse-any-function)"

```
func FuncAnalyse(m interface{}) {

    //Reflection type of the underlying data of the interface
    x := reflect.TypeOf(m)

    numIn := x.NumIn()   //Count inbound parameters
    numOut := x.NumOut() //Count outbounding parameters

    fmt.Println("Method:", x.String())
    fmt.Println("Variadic:", x.IsVariadic()) // Used (<type> ...) ?
    fmt.Println("Package:", x.PkgPath())
}
```